# Error: Failed to calculate BLAKE2b digest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am facing issues while generating Pasetos token and

```
Pasetos.V2.LOCAL.builder()
.setSharedSecret(secretKey)
.setIssuedAt(now)
.setExpiration(now.plus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
.setSubject(userPrincipal.getUsername())
.setKeyId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
.setAudience(“bootlabs.com”)
.setIssuer(“dev.com”)
.claim(“aut”, authorities)
.compact();
throws-
```

Error: Failed to calculate BLAKE2b digest

Using - spring boot version - 3.0.2

Any ideas on how to resolve the error?

I am trying to generate the PASETO tokens in a springboot application